# best way to record all app data

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, wcf

I'm needed to add to my app(Client-Side,WPF,WCF,C#,.Net 4.5.1,Win7) a feature that will record all the main data of the app, and will be able to play it back to the app as if the data was received from the Server-Side.
The recording time is maxed to 5min or memory size of file/data(1.28GB).

I have 3 main object types:

1. 500 instances (class with ~100 properties) - updates every 300ms
2. One large object (class with ~6000 child, sub-child etc.) - updates every 5s
3. 2 objects (class with ~ 30 properties) - updates every 1s

---

I need this feature to be done on the Client-Side. I want the solution to be as much as optimal performance-wise.
I've thought to solve this problem by writing the data to binary files 
and play them back from there. or to use a SQL server. 
I'm open to any other suggestion.

Comment: 500 + 1 + 2, that's 503 objects, not 3 objects

Comment: you need to use a message broker like mirosoft service bus (event hub) so your server can have enough time to process your data

Comment: I meant 3 object types. I receive the data from the server by events. the performance of the server is quiet good. which solution should i use?

Comment: Check out RabbitMQ for very robust messaging platform: https://www.rabbitmq.com/

Comment: you are suggesting a message platform, why not to use a UDP with a queue at the receiving side? I've also implemented a live logger using ETW, why not to use it for the same purpose?